# Python 3.5 shortcut vs IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed Python 3.5 on Windows. What is the difference between the Python 3.5 and the IDLE shortcuts?

They seem to do the same.  Both provide a command line that you can execute Python code on.

Here's what each shortcuts links to:

IDLE:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\pythonw.exe
```

Python 3.5

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
```

Comment: Idle could refer to python 2.7 if you have both installed.. Oh, and Idle also comes with a notepad like editor, the python interpreter does not

Comment: Where are you seeing these shorcuts? Why not see what they're linking to?

Comment: Please explain better what do you mean by "the Python 3.5 and the IDLE shortcuts"

Comment: Both icons are in the Python group.

Comment: @Leb: Thanks.  Looks like I should use the regular python.exe version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE is Python’s Integrated Development and Learning Environment.

It has the following features:

- Coded in 100% pure Python, using the tkinter GUI toolkit
- Cross-platform: works mostly the same on Windows, Unix, and Mac OS X
- Python shell window (interactive interpreter) with colorizing of code input, output, and error messages
- Multi-window text editor with multiple undo, Python colorizing, smart indent, call tips, auto completion, and other features
- Search within any window, replace within editor windows, and search through multiple files (grep)
- Debugger with persistent breakpoints, stepping, and viewing of global and local namespaces
- Configuration, browsers, and other dialogs

Python shell is a simple shell, which is actually used by IDLE.

More info: https://wiki.python.org/moin/IDLE

Comment: ah - now I see these features in IDLE.  Great answer.